# Quarkus Docker App Running Differently Locally vs Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, quarkus, vert.x

Using the generic Dockerfile provided by Quarkus, we try to create a Docker instance of an app to then deploy in our Kubernetes environment:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-11:1.14

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'

COPY --chown=185 ourApp/target/*-runner.jar /deployments/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
USER 185
ENV AB_JOLOKIA_OFF=""
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/app.jar"

WORKDIR /deployments
```

All of this works great locally - but once deployed to Kubernetes, we suddenly get a vertx.impl error:

```
$ kubectl logs -f po/app-11111111-ddddd -n appNamespace
io.quarkus.opentelemetry.runtime.exporter.otlp.LateBoundBatchSpanProcessor logDelegateNotFound
WARN: No BatchSpanProcessor delegate specified, no action taken.
Dec 22, 2022 8:05:03 PM io.quarkus.runtime.StartupContext runAllInReverseOrder
ERROR: Running a shutdown task failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.current(ContextInternal.java:46)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.currentContext(Vertx.java:117)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.runtime.VertxCurrentContextFactory$VertxCurrentContext.get(VertxCurrentContextFactory.java:30)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.RequestContext.destroy(RequestContext.java:177)
    at io.quarkus.arc.ManagedContext.terminate(ManagedContext.java:36)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.shutdown(ArcContainerImpl.java:382)
    at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.shutdown(Arc.java:58)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder$1.run(ArcRecorder.java:47)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.StartupContext.runAllInReverseOrder(StartupContext.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.StartupContext.close(StartupContext.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:110)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)

Dec 22, 2022 8:05:03 PM io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager run
ERROR: Failed to start application (with profile prod)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory
    at io.vertx.core.impl.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:26)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AddressResolver.<clinit>(AddressResolver.java:39)
    at io.vertx.core.dns.AddressResolverOptions.<clinit>(AddressResolverOptions.java:79)
    at io.vertx.core.VertxOptions.<init>(VertxOptions.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.initialize(VertxCoreRecorder.java:201)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:610)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:592)
    at io.quarkus.opentelemetry.runtime.OpenTelemetryRecorder.storeVertxOnContextStorage(OpenTelemetryRecorder.java:47)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.OpenTelemetryProcessor$storeVertxOnContextStorage1193902621.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.OpenTelemetryProcessor$storeVertxOnContextStorage1193902621.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:110)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
```

This happens no matter what configurations I change - I can't seem to get past it.

Once again, this WORKS LOCALLY with the *SAME* Docker image.  Once deployed, it suddenly cant find the class definition.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  Is this masking another error that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: update: It appears this does not happen until we go from Quarkus v2.10 -> v2.11.  Perhaps a setting or configuration that we are missing?

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError with message "Could not initialize class XYZ" does not mean that class XYZ could not be found. It means that the JVM has already tried and failed to load that class before, so doesn't bother attempting to load it a second time. If you go back through the logs for your app, do you get a different exception (in particular an ExceptionInInitializerError)? Perhaps try restarting your app.

Comment: @LukeWoodward so here is the kicker.  We have tried all of that.  The project boots up fine (via java or the same docker image) locally, but when deployed to Kubernetes it has the NoClassDefFoundError - the same 2 each time.  No amount of restarts helps.  Why does this work locally and not deployed?  The configurations are also *the same* after a lot of comparisons/diffs.

Comment: @jbkc85 does this still happen with the latest version of Quarkus?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I've never really worked much with Kubernetes so I can't say quite what is going wrong here.

Comment: It looks similar to this issue https://github.com/reactiverse/reactiverse-contextual-logging/issues/52

Can you try to upgrade Vert.x to 4.3.4 in your project? It fixes the issue linked above